# I want to get the user info through Last.fm API by Pylast

Tags: python, api, last.fm

I want to get the user info through Last.fm API by Pylast,but it returns error: bound method,I think I need your help.

```
import pylast

API_KEY = "xxx"
API_SECRET = "xxx"

username = "xxx"
password_hash = pylast.md5("xxx")

network = pylast.LastFMNetwork(api_key = API_KEY, api_secret = API_SECRET, username =  username, password_hash = password_hash)

#Get User Info
user = pylast.User('xxx',network=network)
print user.get_id
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. Add the complete traceback info for starters...

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error, it's just telling you that `user.get_id` is a function **bound** to an object.

I think what you need is `print user.get_id()` to call that function and see what it gives you... Make sure you know what functions are :)